# Randomly Select Data from A Large Text File

Tags: python

I am working with 8GB RAM in 64 bit Windows7.

I have a text file of 30GB with one column of numeric data.

I have to randomly select 5% of its lines randomly.
I started as follows:

```
fi = "data.txt"
lines = fi.read().splitlines()

Memory Error...
```

Do you have any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "about 5 %" is good enough for you, you could read the file line by line, and give each line a 5 % chance to be included in your list:

```
import random
result = []
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if random.random() < 0.05:
            result.append(line)
```